# The mentioned syntax error was in this while loop

Tags: bash, syntax

I ran the below code through shellcheck myscript and keep getting this error. How can I correct it?

```
****Line 48:
 while [ $count - lt 3 ]

 ^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this while loop.
       ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.**
                ^-- SC1076: Trying to do math? Use e.g. [ $((i/2+7)) -ge 18 ].
                 ^-- SC1072: Expected a test operator. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.**
```

```
 #!/bin/bash
 touch.bash_profile 
  mkdir login.sh 
  chmod + x login.sh 
  echo "Enter Your Username." 
  read user 
  echo "Enter Your Password." 
 read pass 
# to check blank inputs
  if [ -z "$user" ] ||
  [ -z "$pass" ] 
 then 
 echo 'Inputs cannot be blank. Please retry.' 
# Checking entered username and password with actual credentials
# if matched
    if [ "$Username" = "Alpha" ] ||
    [ "$Password" = "Beta" ] ;
then 
 pwd 
  else
# if not matched
      count = 1 
 while [ $count - lt 3 ]
      do
if["$Username" != "$user"]
      ||["$Password" != "$pass"];
then 
 left = 3 - $count 
 echo b
```

Comment: Welcome, `- lt` should be `-lt`.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting:

Line 48:
while [ $count -lt 3 ]
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this while loop.
 
Line 56:
if [ "$Username" != "$user" ]||
^-- SC1046: Couldn't find 'fi' for this 'if'.
^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this if expression. Fix to allow more checks.
 
Line 66:
 echo b
       ^-- SC1047: Expected 'fi' matching previously mentioned 'if'.
       ^-- SC1072: Expected 'fi'. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

Comment: Each `if ... then ... ` construct needs to be terminated by a `fi`

Comment: @Amber1993 Is this your code or is it copied from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think I have the flow correct.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create the files .bash_profile and login.sh in the current directory making the login.sh executable.

touch .bash_profile 
touch login.sh 
chmod +x login.sh 

# Tell them what needs to be done

echo "This script requires you to enter the Username and Password, you have three tries at it."

# set the count to 0
count=0
while [ $count -lt 3 ] ; do

    # Check for Username

    echo "Enter Your Username:" 
    read user 
    if [ -z "$user" ] ; then
        echo "You must enter a Username"
    fi
    
    # Check for Password

   echo "Enter Your Password:" 
    read pass 
    if [ -z "$pass" ] ; then
        echo "You must enter a Password"
    fi
    
    #checking entered username and password with actual credentials

    #if matched $Username and $Password

    if [ "$user" = "Alpha" ] && [ "$pass" = "Beta" ] ; then
         pwd 
         exit 0

    else

    #if not matched

        let "count+=1" 
        echo "This is try number $count "
    fi
done
```

The output when you run it and the contents of the directory afterwards.

```
root@buster-raspi:~/test# ./test.sh
This script requires you to enter the Username and Password, you have three tries at it.
Enter Your Username
test
Enter Your Password
trtet
This is try number 1 
Enter Your Username
test
Enter Your Password
rsrseres
This is try number 2 
Enter Your Username
dsddsf
Enter Your Password
gfdggdf
This is try number 3 
root@buster-raspi:~/test# ./test.sh
This script requires you to enter the Username and Password, you have three tries at it.
Enter Your Username
test
Enter Your Password

You must enter a Password
This is try number 1 
Enter Your Username
root@buster-raspi:~/test# ./test.sh
This script requires you to enter the Username and Password, you have three tries at it.
Enter Your Username
Alpha
Enter Your Password
Beta
/root/test
root@buster-raspi:~/test# ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   0 Feb 26 22:06 login.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 927 Feb 26 22:05 test.sh
root@buster-raspi:~/test# ls -l .bash_profile 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 26 22:11 .bash_profile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 927 Feb 26 22:05 test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome,  just get your problem one item at a time in your work flow, like I think I mentioned. Then move onto the next item in your script, test it all the way after each step to confirm it does it, with echo's where the command is to be run. Once the logic is in place your put in the commands and test again.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to be tidy and organized to write code. [Here you have a guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html), not mandatory, but a good place to start.

Google the gnu manual to learn the proper syntax and such. A search could be *"bash gnu manual constructs"*, and for me the first result [is this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html).

Regarding your code, and following my suggestions:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
touch.bash_profile 
mkdir login.sh 
chmod + x login.sh 
echo "Enter Your Username" 
read user 
echo "Enter Your Password" 
read pass 
#to check blank inputs
if [ -z "$user" ] || [ -z "$pass" ]; then 
    echo 'Inputs cannot be blank. Please re-try.' 
    #checking entered username and password with actual credentials
    #if matched
    if [ "$Username" = "Alpha" ] || [ "$Password" = "Beta" ];then 
        pwd 
    else
        #if not matched
        count=1 
        while [ $count -lt 3 ]; do
            if [ "$Username" != "$user" ] || [ "$Password" != "$pass" ]; then
                left=$((3 - $count ))
                echo b
            fi
        done
    fi
fi
```

This has passed the `shellcheck` syntax.